# React - How to render a list from keys of array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, but not Javascript.

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
[
 { "Environments": ["DEV", "QA", "PROD"] },
 { "Products": ["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"] },
 { "Releases": [1,2,5] }
]
```

I want to render a list in HTML list this:

```
<ul>  
 <li>Environments</li>
 <li>Products</li>
 <li>Releases</li>
</ul>
```

I use the following (ugly) Javascript to iterate over the list to get the keys:

```
var topics = [
    { "Environments": ["DEV", "QA", "PROD"] },
    { "Products": ["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"] },
    { "Releases": [1,2,5] },
]

topics.map(topic => { 
    Object.entries(topic).map( ([key, values]) => { 
        console.log(key);
        console.log(values);
    })
})
```

But when I try to apply it in a react component it, I get nothing, no error.

```
export default function() 
{
    const topics = //...topics from json
    
    return (
        <>
        <h1>Topics</h1>
        <ul>
            
            {topics.map(topic => { Object.entries(topic).map( ([key, values]) => { 
                <li>key: {key}</li>
            })})}
        </ul>
        </>
   )
}
```

There is probably (should be) an easier way to present the data I want, but why does React choke on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the expressions from your map function.

```
{topics.map(topic => { return Object.entries(topic).map(([key, values]) => { 
    return <li>key: {key}</li>
})})}
```

or use implicit returns by removing the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```js
{
    topics.map(topic => {//with return and brackets
        return Object.entries(topic).map(([key, values]) => {
            return <li>key: {key}</li>
        })
    })
}
```

```js
{
    topics.map(topic =>
        Object.entries(topic).map(([key, values]) =>
            <li>key: {key}</li>
        )
    )
}
```

in javascript ,the function body will return undefined as default when with brackets,if without brackets it will return the result of the function body